# Make fix (non-moving) dark background

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

On my website. I have the following page:
[image]

When you click on the photo of a car, the background becomes darker (typical front-end idea):
[image]
The problem is, it is movable :( See (I scrolled a bit down):
[image]

So it's a huge issue and needs debugging. How to fix that? How to make background unscrollable or maybe whatever idea you come up with. Thanks!

Comment: add overflow: hidden on body element once popup is open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to guess without any code - but it seems like some kind of lightbox. So try adding

```
  body { overflow: hidden; }
```

when the lightbox is open and

```
  body { overflow: auto;}
```

when it is closed.

Comment: yeah, thanks, it seems to be helpful, I ll try that and I wasn't writing the front-end so don't know what this part of the code looks like but it should be a lightbox. thanks